# how can i restore the pre-trained model built with Estimator API?

Tags: model, restore

Thanks in advance.

i'm new to tensorflow, and followed this tutorial to train this model. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers i want to restore this model in another place to get the prediction. but i can't find a way. have been working on this for two days and still don't know how to do it.i'll be very appreciate if anyone can offer me some advice.
i have tried the following.

```
saver=tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')
```

i think with these above i have restored my model? but how can i reach the operations?
please don't shoot me if i asked stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the estimator classifier has predict.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py

```
predict_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x":x_value},batch_size=1,shuffle=False)
predict_result=mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn,predict_keys="classes")
```

then the problem solved.^ ^